# Could we have the "Last 30 days" answers link actually lead to the answers posted in the last 30 days?

Tags: feature-request, bug, top-users

The gripe I have is with the Top Users page for any given tag.  Under *"Top [tag] answerers"* there are two tables, titled *"Last 30 Days"* and *"All Time"*.  For example [top [Discussion] users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/topusers).

Alongside the users in those tables are the number of answers they have provided in the given time frame, and the number of upvotes they have received on those answers.

The column that shows the number of answers provided is also a hyperlink that leads to the answers provided by that user. However, if you click that link in the *"Last 30 Days"* table, you're still taken to a page that shows *all* the answers that user has posted in the given tag, not just the ones he/she posted in the last 30 days.

I consider this a bug, or at least a missing feature.

Comment: I never realised that the number of answers is also a hyperlink as nothing makes it apparent (besides the cursor changing shape).

Answer (score 12):

For some reason, that link doesn't append any date parameters to the built in search.  So click on [Brad's Discussion answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:19679%20[discussion]%20is:answer) produces this link:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:19679%20[discussion]%20is:answer
```

Advanced searching is fully capable of adding date criteria, so it looks like an oversight.  Adding something like `created:30d..` would be helpful.  Even better, the system could use the actual timestamp from whenever those stats are updated daily minus 30 days.  For example, [Brad's discussion answers in the last 30 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:19679%20[discussion]%20is:answer%20created%3A30d..)

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:19679%20[discussion]%20is:answer%20created%3A30d..
```